# Retrieve property info from dynamic by Reflection

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

**ADDED:** What I want to do. I have something, for example, DataReader, from which I want to create IEnumerable of objects with members as in DataReader. So, in design and compile time I don't know how many properties will be in my dynamic object (depends on how many columns contains in DataReader) and it names. AND I need to create such dynamic anonymous object  with properties with right names and values, to get this properties in future by reflection...

I thought about DynamicObject and that's what I've done:

I have DynamicObject class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Linq;

namespace makarov.ReportManager.InternalLogic
{
public class DataReaderParcer : DynamicObject
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, object> m_properties;

    public DataReaderParcer()
    {
        m_properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    public bool SetMember(string name, object value)
    {
        if (m_properties.ContainsKey(name))
            m_properties.Remove(name);
        m_properties.Add(name, value);
        return true;
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        return SetMember(binder.Name, value);
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        result = null;
        if (m_properties.ContainsKey(binder.Name))
            result = m_properties[binder.Name];
        return m_properties.ContainsKey(binder.Name);
    }

    public override IEnumerable<string> GetDynamicMemberNames()
    {
        return from p in m_properties select p.Key;
    }
}
```

}

And here is the usage:

```
   dynamic dd = new DataReaderParcer();
        dd.MyMember= 3;
        dd.YourMember= "hello";
```

How to retrieve PropertyInfo[] of this object using Reflection in another method? Something like this `dd.GetType().GetProperties()` doesn't work correctly because DataReaderParcer don't have any properties.

Comment: As there are no properties, what do you want to get in your ProperyInfo[] ?

Comment: Side note, Parcer - do you mean Parser?

Comment: Yes, Parser. I want to get my dynamic properties...

Comment: Why don't you use `var members = (dd.GetDynamicMemberNames() as IEnumerable<string>).ToList();`

Answer (score 3):

You are derriving from DynamicObject therefore you can call GetDynamicMemberNames to get an enumeration your members.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.getdynamicmembernames.aspx

```
dynamic dd = new DataReaderParcer();
IEnumerable<string> members = dd.GetDynamicMemberNames();
```

Comment: Yes, and I even override this method. But problem is that I don't know if it normal object or dynamic, but yes, I can solve it in "if" statement, but I don't like this idea. But next I need to get value of properties, that I'll get in GetDynamicMemberNames method...